# Load balancing through TCP and disabling re-use of HTTP connection on Go servers

Tags: go

I am trying to find a way to load balance incoming requests on my Go servers. I have tried nginx, haproxy and some Go repositories on GitHub like:

https://github.com/darkhelmet/balance

that allows you to do layer 4 load balancing through TCP.

I have tried TCP load balancing through haproxy and through the darkhelmet/balance library. It seems like when I do load balancing through TCP, my connections are re used so every request from my PC gets sent to the same server. So it becomes hard for me to do benchmarks with for example the "wrk" benchmarking tool. And also other tests when I need to see if websocket connections on different go apps can communicate through a redis server via pub sub methods and so on.

When I refresh the web browser I can see that all requests are sent to the same server, even tho I have 3 Go servers in the backend.

Someone said this to me: "Disable HTTP connection re-use on your web servers." But I do not know how to do this.

The code I use for my go servers to benchmark is this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

func fib(n int) int {
    if n == 0 {
        return 0
    } else if n == 1 {
        return 1
    } else {
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    }
}

func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/", toHandle(root))
    router.GET("/fibonacci/:n", toHandle(fibonacci))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":80", router))
}

type errHandle func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request, httprouter.Params) error

func toHandle(eh errHandle) httprouter.Handle {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
        if err := eh(w, r, ps); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    }
}

func root(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) error {
    w.Write([]byte("To the moon! goapp1"))
    return nil
}

func fibonacci(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) error {
    n, err := strconv.Atoi(ps.ByName("n"))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    result := fib(n)
    w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("result: %d", result)))
    return nil
}
```

How can I achieve this? To be able to do roundrobin from the same client/ip/machine through tcp load balancing?

Comment: You simply can't load balance at the transport layer, and have it distribute requests based on the session layer or higher. The load balancer must understand the protocol you expect it to load-balance.

Comment: But if I loadbalance through http, won't that make some things much more complicated? Such as working with websockets?

Comment: No, but if the client assumes the same server will respond within a single http/1.1 or http2 session it can cause problems (note, I'm not sure offhand if either nginx or haproxy will distribute individual requests within a single session). In practice this is an artificial problem you've created for yourself. If you have a system under enough load to matter, you usually have enough clients to have the load distributed evenly anyway.